# To write java method in PL/SQL

Tags: java, plsql

Is it possible to write a java method within a PL/SQL block?

Please eloborate this using an example...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No its not, but you can write JSP (Java Stored Procedure). For that, you can find a tutorial over here, [Developing Java Stored Procedures](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm#BABGCGBG).